# How can I run 'ls' with options from a C program?

Tags: shell, c

I want to execute the command `ls -a` using `execv()` on a Linux machine as follows:

```
char *const ptr={"/bin/sh","-c","ls","-a" ,NULL};
execv("/bin/sh",ptr);
```

However, this command does not list hidden files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you do `sh -c ls -a` (same as `"sh" "-c" "ls" "-a"`) at a shell prompt?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure why you're passing this via `/bin/sh`... but since you are, you need to pass all the arguments after `-c` as a single value because these are now to be interpreted by `/bin/sh`.

The example is to compare the shell syntax of

```
/bin/sh -c ls -a
```

to

```
/bin/sh -c 'ls -a'
```

The second works, but the first doesn't.

So your `ptr` should be defined as

```
char * const ptr[]={"/bin/sh","-c","ls -a" ,NULL};
```

Comment: You caught two, but missed a third.  `ptr` is not being declared as the correct type.

Comment: Note that a shell isn't needed to call an external command: you can just use `{"/bin/ls", "-a", NULL}`.

Comment: @deltab - yes, and if `/bin/sh` is wanted then `system()` would also work.  I just took the opportunity to explain why `sh -c` needs the arguments in one parameter :-)

Comment: No, not `system`, never

Comment: @Dani `system()` effectively does `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) NULL)` and so is pretty much what the above code does, anyway!

Answer (score 5):

If you need to get the contents of a directory from a [c](/questions/tagged/c) program, then this is not the best way - you will effectively have to parse the output of `ls`, which is [generally considered a bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Instead you can use the `libc` functions [`opendir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html) and [`readdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html) to achieve this.

Here is a small example program that will iterate over (and list) all files in the current directory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    DIR *dirp;
    struct dirent *dp;

    dirp = opendir(".");
    if (!dirp) {
        perror("opendir()");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((dp = readdir(dirp))) {
        puts(dp->d_name);
    }

    if (errno) {
        perror("readdir()");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note the listing will not be sorted, unlike the default `ls -a` output.